# How to use the Spotify Access Token outside of an Express Route

Tags: node.js, express, spotify

I am currently learning Node.js and Express and wanted to build a simple app that queries the Spotify Web API without using an external library such as [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node). My code is available at https://pastebin.com/Jwe8sckJ

My "/callback" route looks like this;

```
app.get("/callback", function(req, res){
    res.send("OK!")
    var authCode = req.query.code
    var options = { method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      form: 
       { grant_type: 'authorization_code',
       code: authCode,
       redirect_uri: 'https://example.com/callback',
       client_id: clientId,
       client_secret: clientSecret } };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
  var refreshToken = JSON.parse(body).refresh_token
  console.log("Access Token: " + accessToken);
  console.log("Refresh Token: " + refreshToken);
    });

});
```

So far this is all working fine, I am able to get an Access Token and a Refresh Token. The part that I am confused about is how do I now use these tokens outside of the "/callback" route? Or maybe another way of asking would be how do I save the variables globally. If I do that, would it have any impact on new sessions to script?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right then you want to save access token for later use. You can declare global variable and can use it later.

```
global.spotify_access_token = '';
```

Declare this variable at the start of any file. Now you can use this variable to save access token in callback.like below :

```
spotify_access_token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution would be to store these tokens in a database, i.e. [MongoDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) or MySQL and retrieve them when needed. You'll probably want to use [sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to set the received tokens per client.

You could even save the tokens in the session, but please note that sessions are volatile.

Comment: What about storing the access token as a cookie in the users browser? These cookies are specific to 1 user only and potentially can be used to gather private user data

Comment: Creating a session using the mentioned library creates a cookie in the background for you. The client stores a cookie with an ID, which it sends to the server along with each requests. The server can then use that cookie's ID to recognize the client.